# Websocket issue with IIS 8 Express on Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, websocket, iis-8

I tried creating handler for web socket but context.IsWebSocketRequest is returning always false and failed to working with IIS 8 Express on windows 7.

How can I enable module for websocket or any step I missing? I have VS 2012 application with IIS Express dynamic url.

Please help for the same.

Comment: If you need WebSockets in Windows 7, you can use my WebSocket connector : http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/

Comment: also, if you are using Kestrel on ASP Net Core - there is no need in 3rd party listener, you can run 'dotnet myApp.dll' and WebSockets will work even on Win7 directly with Kestrel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The WebSocket protocol needs to be enabled in IIS 8 (see http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/programming-html5-web-sockets-in-asp.net-4.5.htm). Additionally, I'm not sure web sockets is supported on Windows 7. I've only seen that Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 are required.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is, you can **write** applications against WebSockets in Windows 7 using IIS 8 Express, but you can't actually **test** them. It requires Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012.

From the [IIS 8.0 Express ReadMe](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme):

> **WebSocket Support**
>
> IIS 8.0 Express supports writing WebSocket applications. For more information, see the WebSocket protocol specification or the System.Net.WebSockets Namespace topic on Microsoft's MSDN website.
>
> **Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8 features that do not work on Down-Level Operating Systems**
>
> There are a few features which require architecture that is specific
> to Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8 Client that will not work
> down-level when you install IIS 8.0 Express on earlier operating
> systems:
>
> Server Name Indication (SNI)
> Central Certificate Store 
> WebSocket Functionality

Then, from the [System.Net.WebSockets MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159285) (emphasis mine):

> Some of the classes in the System.Net.WebSockets namespace are supported on Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, and Windows Server 2008. *However, the only public implementations of client and server WebSockets are supported on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.* The classes and class elements in the System.Net.WebSockets namespace that are supported on Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, and Windows Server 2008 are abstract classes. This allows an application developer to inherit and extend these abstract classes with an actual implementation of client WebSockets.

Comment: I tried WebSockets on Windwos 7 and did not get it to work. Besides the unbelievable fact that web sockets require OS upgrades not only for servers but even all dev machines I am shocked and confused about the msdn entry: "the only public implementations of client and server WebSockets are supported on Win 8 ...". Please what??? Classes are a programming language concept. What mess is this with classes and OS ? This sounds really bizarre to me.

Comment: What about Windows 10?