# SignalR client function not called

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have several places in my application where SignalR is working fine, but for some reason on this hub, my client method is never getting called.

JS:

```
var fundingAdequacyHub;
$(function () {
    fundingAdequacyHub = $.connection.fundingAdequacyHub;

    fundingAdequacyHub.client.broadcastStateChange = function (id, result) {
        console.log('state changed');
    };

    var connection = fundingAdequacyHub.connection;
    connection.start().done(hubReady); 
});

function hubReady(){
    fundingAdequacyHub.server.stateChange(1, "new state");
}
```

In my C#, this method is getting fired when I call a server method, but `broadcastStateChange` is never being fired on the client

```
public void StateChange(int id, string vm)
{
    //breakpoint here, no errors generated or anything when it goes past this line
    Clients.All.broadcastStateChange(id, vm);
}
```

Why is `broadcastStateChange` not being called? What am I doing wrong? Similar questions I found on SO were saying i wasn't binding the method before starting the hub, but I am doing that.

I also tried turning on logging for the `connection`. I see the server method be called, but no output saying the client method was called.

I am also experiencing very slow connections, which might be another symptom of the real problem. I tried stripping my hub down to not make any database calls or anything, but am still getting very slow hub startup times and the delay between calling the `server.stateChange()` and the debug breakpoint being hit on the server can be a few seconds long. Any ideas about what could be causing that slow performance? I have other hubs on the site that are working fine, and this one is simpler than those.

A bit more info: I found that this same code works fine when deployed on the server, it's only not working when running on my local machine.

I was able to get the client method to fire *once* by stepping through the code slowly, but was not able to reproduce it.

**Update 5/13/2015**

I did some digging in the developer tools, specifically the network tab. On localhost, there is some kind of polling taking place, a connection that gets opened for ~20 seconds and then closes and a new one opens. The timeline gets extended over and over. When running on the server, however, I see that it sets up a web socket, the timeline stays the same, and everything is working fine. So it seems that on localhost, SignalR isn't using a web socket and is failing to work properly.

Localhost SignalR log

```
SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'fundingadequacyhub'.
SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22fundingadequacyhub%22%7D%5D'.
SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:200/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProto…%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22fundingadequacyhub%22%7D%5D&tid=9'.
SignalR: EventSource connected.
SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request.
SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
```

Server SignalR Log

```
SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'fundingadequacyhub'.
SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22fundingadequacyhub%22%7D%5D'.
SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://intranet:200/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=0TdJtNtl6Vm0PszuLIIliTk1jez5v%2BmRH0edUKti3NX7Cmop5frD9u%2BCUjD4f3PeFGjneFwT85MTLqwXFIQakB3VzwD8ISoYHn3LaABVvQhfC1Fzy9fkPYlOyLAkInD8YZoCeCVMEKKmb7S%2FLacIDQ%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22fundingadequacyhub%22%7D%5D&tid=0'.
SignalR: Websocket opened.
SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
```

**Another Update...**

So it would seem that websockets [aren't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995420/526704) by Windows 7, my development machine. However, I have other pages using SignalR that work as I would expect, so there's something wrong with `serverSentEvents` mode that's failing.

**Hopefully final update**

And now, inexplicably, it's working fine. I don't know what has changed, but it's working now. What I had done was instead of starting my hub with `start()`, I started it with `start({ transports: ['webSockets']})`, which failed to connect because sockets aren't supported on windows 7. When I removed that clause again and switched back to `start()`, it started working.

Comment: Are you calling the server BroadcastStateChange anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes, like i said I put a breakpoint in the C# method and it is being called.

Comment: Try placing the code directly inside a hub method and not an external one

Comment: you mean `Clients.All.broadcast...`? I did that, no luck. Also it shouldn't matter.

Comment: No i mean that you should try to remove any abstractions you have on the server just for testing and invoke the client method directly inside any of the server hub declared methods to see if it works

Comment: not really sure what you mean, there are no abstractions. If i call `fundingAdequacyHub.server.broadcastStateChange(1, "test")`, the method fires on the server but the client `broadcastStateChange` does not. I tried changing it on the server side to just `StateChange(int, string)` in case the names were overriding somehow, but that didn't do anything. I've updated my answer with the code i'm calling to the server