# Are IIS(Internet Information Services) versions dependent on windows operating system?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am new to IIS world, and I was trying to see what IIS is running at my local machine. I have windows 7 and when I go to help->about of IIS manager, a pop up shows up, whose second line says "Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)", so I thought this is version 6.1 of IIS. However right at the end of same Pop up I can see another line "Internet Information Services(Version 7.4.7600.16385)".

now I am confused which IIS version I am running 6.1 or 7.5?
I have done bit of research and found out that IIS version 7.5 belongs to Windows7. Can I safely assume that if I have windows7 I can not have IIS version other than 7.5?

Is there any good tutorial/ reading material online to understand IIS and how it works?

Comment: @JustAnotherDotNetDev, can you please provide some evidence for your answer-in-a-comment?  I don't believe you are correct.  For example, how would I install IIS 8.5 on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 1):

IIS is tied to the operating system.

This is a little old post, but just thought I'd share.  Here it is in a book!

[Section: **IIS 8.0 Requirements** - in the Second Sentence of that section.](https://books.google.com/books?id=0HpTzjw9EZQC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=iis%20tied%20to%20operating%20system&source=bl&ots=YiJdcey407&sig=rCQvM5U-fnd_n7Lf0i4iSiWK15k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ3bmWwZHKAhXFVD4KHVvFBZYQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=iis%20tied%20to%20operating%20system&f=false)

Update in response to Himanshu Singh's answer, because I can't comment:  I wanted to talk about 'upgrading' and to IIS 8.0 Express.  I am specifically interested in IIS 8.0 because of websockets, IIS 8.0 Express doesn't support websockets, so it isn't a 'true upgrade'.  I dont know what features it supports from 8.0, because I stopped reading about it after learning it doesnt support the websockets protocol.

Here where I found information about IIS 8.0 Express not supporting websockets.

[Websocket issue with IIS 8 Express on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249067/websocket-issue-with-iis-8-express-on-windows-7)

Also, to answer the question directly, yes you can 'safely' assume your version of IIS is 7.5

Answer (score 0):

You can  definitely install other version of IIS on Win7. Like IIS Express 8.0 will run on Windows Vista with SP1 and all later versions of Windows.

To study IIS online you can definitely go to http://www.iis.net/

Comment: IIS express and IIS are not the same.