# SignalR don't use websockets on IIS Express 10

Tags: websocket, .net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-signalr

I have .NET Core 2.2 + ASP.NET Core 2.2 with SignalR inside. In my development environment I have Win7 with IIS Express 10.

Unfortunately, SignalR don't use WebSockets and unfortuantely I didn't found a way to force it to do so.

On the server side, SignalR is configured like this:

```
app.UseSignalR(
    routeBuilder => routeBuilder
        .MapHub<ClientsHub>(
            "/hubs/clients",
            options => options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
);
```

On the client side configuration is:

```
this._connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(this.api.getHubUrl(url), {
    transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  })
  .build();
```

Negotiate request from the client side of SignalR results with this answer:

```
{"connectionId":"1SyteS9TsDE5Q8LBRb2-VA","availableTransports":[]}
```

As a result, client side of SignalR writes this message to the console:

```
Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Unable to initialize any of the available transports.
```

This obviously means that websockets are not used and SignalR can't initialize websockets.

I've found using Google that IIS Express has websockets disabled by default and I have to enable them first. I've found some setting in IISExpress/config folder in file applicationhost.config and set it to Allow (it was Deny by default):

```
<section name="webSocket" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

But nothing changes.

If to disable negotiation, SignalR client tries to use WebSockets directly using url like this:

```
wss://localhost:44360/hubs/clients
```

But this request results with error code 400:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Is there any possibility to force SignalR over IIS 10 to use WebSockets?
Or to force IIS 10 to allow SignalR to use WebSockets?

Comment: I am also having this issue using VS2017. IISExpress basically ignores the ws:// initial connection request and I can see nothing debugging side that indicates that the request was even heard.  However, when debugging directly against the web project as a standalone Kesteral host it runs fine and quickly upgrades to wss://. Additionally, I am not using any of the forces protocols like you are above, but have had to resort to forcing SSE in IISExpress. Additional note, It does not look like the IIS web host is accepting ws:// connections either, if that's relevant.

Comment: did you find any solution because I am facing the same situation

Answer (score 1):

I am not having an answer to your question but the reasons.

Window 7 doesn't support web sockets for IIS Express. The SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11050208/1041457) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995420/1041457) justify it.

However, if you use *Kestrel web server* to run your project, it will definitely use Web sockets on Window 7. I have tested the same in a project built on .NET Core 3.1 with VS 2019.

[image: launchSettings.json]